# Is HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode considered for single-quotes attributes?

Tags: .net, encoding

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The string result from the HtmlAttributeEncode method should be used only for double-quoted attributes. Security issues might arise when using the HtmlAttributeEncode method with single-quoted attributes.

Anything I found in my searches was saying that `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode` does **not** encode apostrophes. However, I tried it for myself and it is escaping it (with `&#39;`). This can be seen in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,46e7e533003d74d8) too:

I couldn't find any official blog post about changing this behaviour. Can someone clarify the actual state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentally, `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode()` does NOT replace apostrophes when using .NET framework 3.5 (and older). It does replace them with framework 4.5. So one has to assume that the behaviour changed; this can be seen by comparing the [documentation for .NET 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The HtmlAttributeEncode method converts only quotation marks ("), ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<) to equivalent character entities.

with the [documentation for .NET 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The HtmlAttributeEncode method encodes characters appropriate for insertion into an HTML attribute value.

Note that even the new documentation still says that the quotation is safe only for double-quoted attribute values. My guess is that while the intent is still to target double-quoted attributes only, Microsoft developers finally realized that most developers don't actually read documentation and *will* use `HtmlAttributeEncode()` for single-quoted attributes, so adding an escape for apostrophes was a nice, formally backward-compatible way to make the world slightly better.

Comment: Just to be sure, the statement "Security issues might arise when using the HtmlAttributeEncode method with single-quoted attributes." in the 4.5 / 4.6 documentation refers to the fact that the code might be run on .NET 3.5? So, there are no known ways how to escape single-qoutes with a HtmlAttributeEncode-d input?

Comment: I think that the statement refers to the idea that they always intended the method to be used only for double-quoted arguments, but they added the escape for apostrophes nonetheless to help the poor sods that do not read documentation. They still don't want to claim support for single-quoted attributes, even though they kind-of added it surreptitiously. If you want to escape apostrophes explicitly, you can always do a String.Replace().